# Macro to emulate \SI macro of siunitx package

Tags: macros, siunitx, optional-arguments, pandoc

I am using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to convert a .tex document into a .docx. The tex document uses the [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) package.

As pandoc can not interpret the macros in the package, I have to write dummies for the macros I use, which will then be used by pandoc. As the docx is simply for review by my co-authors, this is not a problem and the final formatting will be done by LaTeX.

I have implemented some macros

```
\newcommand{\percent}{percent}
\newcommand{\per}{/}

\newcommand{\num}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\numrange}[2]{#1 to #2}
\newcommand{\numlist}[1]{#1}

\newcommand{\si}[1]{#1}
```

but I am struggling with `\SI`, particularly the preunit part

```
\SI{number}[preunit]{unit}
```

as the second argument `[preunit]` is the optional argument. I have found that I can specify the first argument as optional argument as follow:

```
\newcommand{\SI}[3][test]{#1#2#3}
```

But how can I do this with the square brackets and as the second argument?

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Pandoc version: pandoc 1.15.2.1

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand{\si}{mO{test}m}` using the `xparse` package, but I am not sure this will work with pandoc

Comment: Shouldn't it read `\SI{number}[preunit]{unit}`?

Comment: Perhaps a [Generic Preprocessor](http://files.nothingisreal.com/software/gpp/gpp.html) could help here. However, I always thought GPP would be better for the markdown-to-*TeX workflow....

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\percent}{percent}
\newcommand{\per}{/}
\newcommand{\kilogram}{kg}
\newcommand{\coulomb}{C}
\newcommand{\mole}{mol}

\newcommand{\num}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\numrange}[2]{#1 to #2}
\newcommand{\numlist}[1]{#1}

\newcommand\svnum{}
\newcommand\SI[2][]{\renewcommand\svnum{#2}\SIhelp}
\newcommand\SIhelp[2][]{\(#1\)\svnum\,#2}
\begin{document}
\SI{23}{m}

\SI{23}[\$]{}

\SI[per-mode=symbol]{1.99}[\$]{\per\kilogram} 

\SI[per-mode=fraction]{1.345}[1000\times]{\coulomb\per\mole}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work with ```pandoc```.

Comment: @Rainer You realize I am showing it with and without `siunitx`.  To make it work in your setting, you need to remove the `siunitx` portion.  Better still, let me restate it without the `siunitx` present.

Comment: @Rainer  How about with this clarification?

Comment: Sure - in the pandoc version I have only the ```Not using siunitx``` section with ``renewcommand``` replaced with ```newcommand```.

Comment: @Rainer I am not a pandoc user, so I can't really say anything more.  But I thought doing it with no packages would suffice.  There is nothing unique in my coding.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I think, it can't work with `pandoc` -- it does not expand the commands correctly :-(

Comment: Thanks a lot - this goes definitely into the right direction. I keep trying along these lines. Could you please explain why this is working as it is as I an=m only a latex user? I assume that the ```\def```` might be throwing ```pandoc``` out - can it be replaced with ```\newcommand```?

Comment: @Rainer I have edited to eliminate the `\def`.

Comment: @Rainer I will be happy to clarify what you need help in understanding, but I am not sure what that is.  I would say the "trick" to getting the optional argument *after* the 1st mandatory argument is the introduction of the `\SIhelp` macro, which is the one that digests the optional argument *after* the 1st mandatory argument has already been absorbed.

Comment: That explains it - and I was not aware of the ```\def````. So no clarificatios here needed anymore - thanks.

Comment: Does not work with pandoc - no idea why. I might have to contact the pandoc guys. Thanks.